# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Search

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have implemented a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to populate cities from the database in to the RecyclerView. After several fails to implement a search feature I am seeking for help. I would like to let users search for a particular city by typing the city's name (postName). The idea is to populate all of the available cities at the beginning and the desired city after its name is typed in the search field.

[image: Firebase database]

[image: App image (Big image)]

My code to populate the view is:

```
   searchField = view.findViewById(R.id.search_field);
    searchButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String search_field = searchField.getText().toString().trim();
            initialiseScreen(view, search_field);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), search_field, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    String search_field = null;
    initialiseScreen(view, search_field);


    return  view;

}

 private void initialiseScreen(final View view, String searchText) {


        Query postQuery = mDataRef.orderByChild("postName").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        mDataRef.keepSynced(true);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.post_RV);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mPostViewAdapter);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions postOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                .setQuery(postQuery, Post.class).build();

        mPostViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(postOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position, final Post model) {

               final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();
               holder.setPostCityImage(model.getImageURL());
               holder.setPostCityName(model.getPostName());
               holder.setLikeBtn(post_key);
               //When is clicked once go to city fragment
               holder.cityImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       //Add code here

                       Intent singlePostIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CitiesActivity.class);
                       singlePostIntent.putExtra("blog_id", post_key);
                       startActivity(singlePostIntent);

                   }
               });

               //Likes button
              holder.likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      mProccessLike = true;

                      String postId = model.getmUid();


                          mDatabaseLikesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                  if(mProccessLike) {

                                      if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(current_user_id)) {


                                          mDatabaseLikesRef.child(post_key).child(current_user_id).removeValue();
                                          mProccessLike = false;

                                      } else {

                                          mDatabaseLikesRef.child(post_key).child(current_user_id).setValue("RandomValue");
                                          mProccessLike = false;

                                      }

                                  }

                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                              }
                          });
                  }
              });
//

            }
```

Btw it populates only one city if instead of **String search_field = null;** I write something like **String search_field = "Calp, Spain";**

Comment: you should type only city name in search and use try `mDataRef.orderByChild("postName").startAt(searchText.split(",")[0].trim());` and how many cities are there with name `calp`

Comment: There is only one city with the name Calp

Comment: Btw your method did not work. It populates the cities but whenever I try to search something it gives me an empty view